# InstantiationException: can't instantiate class .. no empty constructor

Tags: android

In the following code it shows an error at `run()`, so if I put the `@override` above the `run()` then app shows error at `draw()`. Someone help in the basic steps. Here is the code:

```java
    private class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine {
            private final Handler handler = new Handler();
            private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    draw();
                }
            };
    }

12-14 00:55:24.111: W/dalvikvm(7141): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sri.alinwallpaper/com.sri.alinwallpaper.MyPoint}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.sri.alinwallpaper.MyPoint; no empty constructor
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.sri.alinwallpaper.MyPoint; no empty constructor
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
12-14 00:55:24.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     ... 11 more
12-14 00:55:37.751: I/Process(7141): Sending signal. PID: 7141 SIG: 9
```

Comment: In which class is `draw()` declared?

Comment: Show us the error messages.

Comment: The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method

Comment: -1 because the "error at draw" has nothing to do with the title. Please focus on one thing at a time. When you solve a problem, *don't continue to say it's a problem*, but rather move onto the next problem .. (and the error message should say exactly what this new problem is)

Comment: @Priyanka No, it's not the same class. You are creating an `Runnable` class in your code, and you also have a `MyWallpaperEngine` class. But then there's probably another class in the same Java file. It's the same file, but not the same class.

Comment: @Priyanka So now there is a 3rd problem not related to either the title or "error at draw" .. consider reflecting upon the approach used to identify a problem. **"InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.sri.alinwallpaper.MyPoint; no empty constructor"** - see, nothing to do with `@Override` or `draw()`.

Comment: FWIW: I've updated the title to confuse less people in the future. There are duplicates about this topic as well.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg i replaced with MyWallpaperEngine.this.draw();

Comment: @Priyanka **PLEASE STOP TRYING RANDOM THINGS AND PROCEED IN A LOGICAL FASHION BASED UPON THE ACTUAL OBSERVED SYMPTOMS** (I cannot stress this enough. I am done with this misguided post.)

Comment: @pst could you update the solution as well bcz it is very helpful for the more people in future.

Comment: Search for `[android] can't instantiate class no empty constructor`. Please do not use SO as a "running debugging session" in the future.

Comment: @pst okay i will try but not sure ha.

Comment: I couldn't agree with @pst more. You have asked (at least tried to ask) three entirely different questions in the same post. Neither of the questions has been very clear at all. Focus on one question at a time please, and **don't reuse a question on StackOverflow for more questions**.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@Override` annotation. It should work fine without.

According to [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484527/android-override-error), this is because *in Java 5 you could not use the @Override annotation with methods that implemented an interface, only with actual overrides of methods from a super class.*

Comment: if i delete the @override it shows error at draw(),

Comment: That's a completely different problem. My first guess is that it should say `MyWallpaperEngine.this.draw();` However, I'm not sure which `draw` method you want to call exactly.

Comment: okay simon it works ,i changed compiler properties 5 to 6.

Comment: To fix your `draw();` problem it should say `MyClass.this.draw();` where `MyClass` is the name of the outermost class in your java file. (For example, if your java file is called "Foo.java" then the code should probably say `Foo.this.draw();`).

Comment: i tried this but app closed unexpectedly.

Comment: @Priyanka The reason for why your app closes unexpectedly is an entirely different question. Please post a new question for that. Also, don't forget to upvote and accept my answer.